# How to get value between ::before & ::after?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I would like to get value from text between ::before ::after in selenium. I suppose it's impossible to do it by xpath, what JSexecutor code I can use?

Value I would like to get:

[image: Value i would like to get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`::before` and `::after` are the *css* and are not printable text. So to print the text **Widget** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.linkbox.margin-bottom-20 > h1.heading")).getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='linkbox margin-bottom-20']/h1[@class='heading']")).getText());
  ```

---

Ideally, to extract the text **Some Text** as the element is a dynamic element, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.linkbox.margin-bottom-20 > h1.heading"))).getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='linkbox margin-bottom-20']/h1[@class='heading']"))).getText());
  ```